# Document Database Design For Forum

Tags: .net, database, database-design, ravendb

I'm putting together a simple forum as a way to dip my toe into document dbs - thinking that it would be relatively straight forward thing to model.

I'm having trouble figuring out exactly how the documents should be stored. Using RavenDB at the moment but I'd imagine it's going to be similar for other doc. dbs.

So basically, there are `Forums` and each forum has a bunch of `Threads` and each thread contains a bunch of `Posts` which are authored by `Users`.

In my head I have it plotted out as having each of these be distinct documents, mainly because each `Forum` could have thousands of `Threads`, and each `Thread` could have thousands of `Posts`. Having non-distinct documents it seems would cause them to become massive over time?

When viewing a page that lists all the `Posts` I want to display the `Author` name (no big deal) and the `Author` post count. Here is where I'm stuck.

I can store the `Author` name in the post as it's unlikely to change, however the `Author` post count is going to constantly change, so this cannot be stored within the `Post`.

So now if I'm displaying a page with 50 posts, I need to perform the relational equivalent of a join to get the current `Author` post count. This indicates to me I'm doing it wrong, unless a document DB is just not a good fit for this scenario?

### Edit

Looks like [Live Projections](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/10/14/ravendb-ndash-live-projections-or-how-to-do-joins-in.aspx) in RavenDB should handle this just fine but I'd still like to field some comments on possible alternative DB designs.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking about a really similar situation. And I came up with the same conclusion as you. But, I was forgetting something, and maybe you're also forgetting the same: Document DB have a very denormalized nature. So, you can use live projections in ravenDB, but for special cases, because the normal thing to do is duplicate the data. For example:

Post:

- ThreadId (needed for filtering)
- Text
- AuthorId
- **AuthorUsername**
- **AuthorLastLogin**
- **AuthorAnything**

In this way, you have the author's id if you need it later, but you have the most used data denormalized and available without joins or live projections.

In the case of author post count, you have to use a map/reduce index. Those index are continusly regenerating. So, when an author make a post, his count wont be updated right away, but it will be **eventually consistent**. That's is an important part of Document DB.

Hope this could help

Comment: The structure you have is basically what I was thinking anyway - having denormalized AuthorNames included in the Post, I was only just stuck on the AuthorPostCount.. if someone has 10,000 posts.. and they make another, I don't want to have to update the 10,000 previous post documents with the new AuthorPostCount value.

Comment: Added to the above, if loading a page with 50 posts, I also don't want to perform 50 extra queries to load the AuthorPostCount for each post, even in it's own index... hrmm

Comment: I see... What about bringing all 50 post counts (or less if the author had posted more than one post) in the same query? Something like the in clause in sql.

Comment: So, are we storing count variable in database, which keeps count of number of posts by that user?

If so, can we not make another table which has authorId, threadId and count.

count will give the number of posts posted by the author on particular thread.

So, If we want total no. of posts by that author, we can sum them up.

PS: I am naive in database. Answered based on the school knowledge.